# Shall I delete this line in sources.list?

Tags: apt, software-center, sudo, 14.10, synaptic

This line `deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted`, Line 63, in sources.list is not known on `sudo apt-get update` and is causing Synaptic Package Manager and Ubuntu Software center to crash. Is it safe to delete this line?

My sources.list looks like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140723)]/ trusty     main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src cdrom:[Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140723)]/     trusty main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security universe
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security multiverse
deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb-src-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a script or a command went haywire and appended `-src` to a lot of `deb`s. You'll have to delete a lot of lines to fix that. Or, to undo this damage, try this command:

```
sed '62,$s/deb-src/deb/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Inspect the output and ensure that:

1. `-src-src` is not seen in any uncommented line (those not beginning with `#`).
2. A line with `deb` is followed by one with `deb-src`.

Once you have checked the output, you can make the changes permanent by running:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '62,$s/deb-src/deb/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

need not to remove it. just remove `-src` from
`deb-src-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted`

to make it look like:

`deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted`

I can see many such errors in your sources.list file. You have to find and edit all of them.

open it in gedit: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

then in gedit, Edit > Search > Replace

Search for: `deb-src-src`
replace with: `deb-src`